# SQL SP: How to return one inactive record along with active records

Tags: sql-server, mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on this peculiar sql stored proc where the business case is as follows:

**Business Case:**
Table Specialties contains all the Specialties and there is a bit field for each record telling if it's Active or Inactive. We always display only the active records from that table in form of dropdown. Users may select a Specialty which can later on be deactivated. New requirement is to be able to pull that Inactive record along with all the active records in the result set.

**Here's how I thought I should do this:**
If no specialty is assigned to the person I am pulling up then the dropdown is going to be populated by all active records.
If there is a inactive specialty associated with the person I am pulling up then I send that specialtyID in stored proc as a parameter and return that inactive records along with active records to populate the dropdown.

**Below is what I got so far:**
So far if I dont pass in any specialtyId then I am returning active specialty records which is working. When I send in a specialtyId  parameter then it just returns that one inactive record but not rest of the other active records. I need the rest of the active records too along with that one inactive record.

```
   DECLARE  @specialtyId  INT = null;
  BEGIN
    IF isnull(@specialtyId,'')=''
      BEGIN
        SELECT SpecialtyID AS Id, Specialty AS Name
          FROM dbo.Specialties
         WHERE IsActive = 1
         ORDER BY Specialty;
      END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SET @specialtyId = @specialtyId ;

        SELECT s.SpecialtyID AS Id, s.Specialty AS Name
          FROM dbo.Specialties s
         WHERE specialtyId = @specialtyId
         GROUP BY s.Specialty, s.SpecialtyID
         HAVING (Specialty IS NOT NULL)
            AND (max(SpecialtyID) IS NOT NULL)
         ORDER BY Name;
      END
  END
```

Comment: Could you possibly include sample data and desired result? Because, it looks to me like a simple WHERE IsActive = 1 OR specialtyId = @specialtyId should work

Comment: Is this for MySQL or for SQL Server? You have tagged both.

Comment: wow @Forrest thanks for that. That is exactly what I was looking for and can't believe I missed it.

Comment: `( SELECT one inactive row ) UNION ALL ( SELECT all active rows )`

Comment: Note: cross-posted to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39725831/3093192)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a simple `WHERE IsActive = 1 OR specialtyId = @specialtyId` should work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who sees this in the future, [the StackOverflow copy of this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725831/sql-sp-how-to-return-one-inactive-record-along-with-active-records) has a fuller answer.

For easy viewing, I copied Lamak's code from the link to below:

```
SELECT  s.SpecialtyID AS Id, 
        s.Specialty AS Name
FROM dbo.Specialties s
WHERE specialtyID = @specialtyId
OR IsActive = 1;
```

Comment: @RDFozz Updated wording.  You are correct, the answer isn't really explained any better but it is a fuller more complete answer.  Also, the comments in the post on SO were helpful to me.